# Strange StrPCopy() AV error and workaround that does not seems to make sense

Tags: delphi

I am running into a strange problem dealing with StrPCopy(). Please take a look at the sample codes below:

```
procedure TForm2.butnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  s : string;
begin
  //-- assign string this way will cause AV when trying to StrPCopy()
  s := 'original string';

  //-- assign string this way works!!!!!!!
  //s := Trim('original string');

  //-- AV error when trying to alter the string
  StrPCopy(PChar(s), PChar('changed'));

  //-- should come back with "changed"
  Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
end;
```

I am using Delphi 10 Seattle. If I try to alter "s" using StrPCopy() I will get AV error. However, I surround my string declaration with Trim(), it will work.

Seems like by surrounding string declaration with Trim() triggers compiler to turn off some sort optimization on that particular string. I just don't know what that is. Please help.

Comment: You might want to read documentation on [PChar](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.PChar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of StrPCopy() call is not safe - regardless of the AV that is eliminated with the use of the new string that is created with the Trim() assignment.

The string datatype is more complex than PChar. It has a length component that magically sits ahead of the pointer and the character data. Casting to a PChar works, but should only be used for reading.

By casting the string to a PChar, you are allowing StrPCopy to blast the 'changed' string into that part of memory. In your example, you're copying in a smaller string, so you're OK memory-wise. The result is a very confused string (length doesn't match the string, there's a null character in the middle), but you're within it's bounds.

If your code was something like...

```
StrPCopy(PChar(s), PChar('changed to this string'));
```

... then your code is overwriting past the string's memory footprint - usually without an immediate AV. You may get away with this. You may not.

Comment: Thank you. Sounds to me like AV is caused by delphi string length check. Unfortunately, I am surrounded by c/c++ developers at my workplace and this is my constant battle. Understanding this helps a lot.

Answer (score 3):

When `s` refers to a literal it points to read only memory. Hence the access violation.

When you make a writeable string with `Trim` then it can be overwritten without a runtime error. That said, you've still destroyed the string because the null terminator and the length don't match.

Your main problem here is the mixing of Delphi strings with null terminated C strings. Stop that abuse and your problems disappear. There is no reason at all for you to call `StrPCopy`. Once you stop doing that and use native Delphi strings you cannot encounter any such problems.

The correct way to write your code is like so:

```
s := 'changed';
```

Comment: Even when calling `Trim()`, if there is nothing to remove, the input string is returned as-is (so no (re)allocation takes place). Thus, calling `Trim()` on a `string` that is pointing to literal data may return a new `string` that still points to the same `literal` data, so you would still be in the same predicament. Even worse, `StrPCopy()` would destroy multiple `string` variables if they are all pointing to the same data internally (refcount > 1). You would need to use `UniqueString()` to ensure a safe and writable `string` before calling `StrPCopy()`.

Comment: My app talks to C++ DLL that is why. StrPCopy() line simulates C++ DLL string alteration (not to exceed the allocated space, of course). I keep getting AV after C++ DLL call. That's how we get here. In fact, I can do this before calling C++ DLL: s[1] := s[1] and app would run fine as well. Just need clarification why.

Comment: I explained why. So did Remy. The code you presented isn't the real code. You changed it from the real code. Which is confusing. String literals aren't writeable. Use UniqueString or SetLength to make writeable strings.

Comment: Of course, it not the real code. I am trying to demonstrate the point without giving you too much code. @DavidHeffernan, please try not too combative. I am simply asking the question. Did you try the codes above before answering my question? I am just trying to understand what happens. So, am I convert literal string to something else by calling s[1] := s[1]; or s := Trim(s);? Because it works.

Comment: Both of those will although Remy explains why Trim is unreliable. UniqueString is the idiomatic way. But don't do any of that in your actual scenario. Use SetLength. By hiding the actual code and usage you've made it really hard for us to give you advice.